# Unable to open my Django db using PGAdmin (via Docker)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to visually browse my Django app's db data using pgadmin4. But I am having an issue connecting to the DB. I tried using both the local host and also Docker's IP address I obtained via 'docker inspect *container name*' but to no avail. Appreciate any help! Following are the database settings in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": env.dj_db_url("DATABASE_URL",
    default="postgres://postgres@db/postgres")
}
```

Following is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/my_backend
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=xyz"
      - "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I tried the following so far:

1. Deleted all images,volumes, containers and restarted using `docker-compose up -d --build`
2. Re-ran the django 'migrate' command
3. Added psql I installed using Brew to the env zsh path.
4. Tried Pgadmin with 2 different hostnames as below

Following are the inputs I have for pgadmin

1. Host name: Tried both localhost and 172.18.0.2
2. Maintaainance DB: postgres
3. username: postgres
4. Password: Left it `Blank`

Following screenshots show the error
[image: With localhost]

[image: With docker's IPAddress]

Comment: You need to make the port accessible from the outside to connect to the db from the host. Add `ports` definition to your compose file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I added the following but still getting the same error as I mentioned in the post (both for localhost and docker provided address) 
ports:
- "5432:5432"